# Creating python dictionary with a particular column value as key and removing that column from value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dataset which i read in to python as tuples, it looks something like the below one,

```
name time  dept  id
--------------------
 b1  2:00pm z1   1
 b2  3:00pm z2   2
 c1  4:00pm y2   1
 b3  3:00pm z3   3
 c4  4:00pm x2   2
```

I am trying to partition my data in to chunks based on the id value. It should be one chunk having all the tuples with value 1 in id column, another chunk with value 2, and so on. What i am thinking is to create a dictionary with id as my key, i could create a dictionary, but the glitch here is to remove id column from my value in dictionary.

Since tuples are immutable, i am not able to remove the id column value, meanwhile i need that column value to keep it as a key in my dictionary.
And I am looking for an optimized version, because my code has to handle millions of tuples. please suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, exactly. Is it something like this?

`{
    '1': [('b1', '2:00pm', 'z1'), ('c1', '4:00pm', 'y2')],
    '2': [('b2', '3:00pm', 'z2'), ('c4', '4:00pm', 'x2')],
    '3': [('b3', '3:00pm', 'z3')]
}`

Comment: Yes. Similar to this. As i want to input each chunk to my algorithm for parallel processing. Algorithm differentiates the chunk based on the key in each chunk.

Comment: Please remove your dictionary example from the question. It just really gets on nerves, as it is completely bad syntax. My python eyes just cannot stand it :)

Comment: I already did that.. That was just a weird assumption of how my output should look like.. :)

Comment: I dont understand why people giving negative mark for this question, if something is not clear, people are always welcome to clarify. I cannot read everyone's mind guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a dict from the file, there is no point putting into tuple to then later make a `dict` from the `tuples`:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    f.next(),f.next() # skip headers
    for line in f:
        name, time, dept, id = line.split()
        d.setdefault(id,[])
        d[id].append((name,time,dept))
print d

{'1': [('b1', '2:00pm', 'z1'), ('c1', '4:00pm', 'y2')], '3': [('b3', '3:00pm', 'z3')], '2': [('b2', '3:00pm', 'z2'), ('c4', '4:00pm', 'x2')]}
```

If the id is always the last element:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(f_csv)
    tuple_attr = tuple(headers)
    data = tuple(tuple(x.split()) for x in f_csv)
    for tup in data:
        d.setdefault(tup[-1],[])
        d[tup[-1]].append(tup[:-1])
```

`tup[-1]` gets the last element for the key  `tup[:-1]` gets all but the last element for our values.

You can avoid making the tuples altogether by just iterating over f_csv:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(f_csv)
    tuple_attr = tuple(headers)
    for ele in f_csv:
        d.setdefault(ele[-1],[])
        d[ele[-1]].append(ele[:-1])
```

Comment: I cannot hard code the column names since it changes based on the dataset. And to add up, my number of columns differ based on the dataset.

Comment: i am not hardcoding any names, the names are irrelevant, I am just splitting the row into four parts. If your number of columns differ how are you putting them into tuples?

Comment: I am doing them like this..                                         with open(filename) as f:
         f_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
         headers = next(f_csv)
         tuple_attr = tuple(headers)
         data = tuple(tuple(x) for x in f_csv)    And i cannot split the row based on these column names because dataset differs every time.

Comment: how are we supposed to know which is the id if you don't know what your data structure looks like?

Comment: It will be my last column in all the dataset. So i guess we can make use of the length function. And to add with that, length of every line in the dataset will be same always.

Comment: @Jeeva: The `len()` function isn't necessary: you can access the last member of a sequence using `seq[-1]`.

Comment: @Jeeva, I have added an answer using your code which takes the last elements and uses it as the key

Comment: @Jeeva: Perhaps you should remove that `data = {(1 : ...` stuff from your question because it's not valid Python syntax. And it's confusing!

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes. I did. sorry for the confusion. Thanks all.

Comment: All's well that ends well. :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That makes sense, i am removing that tuple factor completely.. :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Actually, Its not working without tuple. There is no split attribute for list. So, i have to use the one with tuple. :(

Comment: @Jeeva, ele[0].split()

Comment: Yeah i tried that, but its taking only the first element in that entire line

Comment: Here you go. I got this by printing ele from f_csv. ['39', ' State-gov', '77516', ' Bachelors', '13', ' Never-married', ' Adm-clerical', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', '2174', '0', '40', ' United-States', ' <=50K', '1']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61164/discussion-between-jeeva-and-padraic-cunningham).